Group by column and spread values into multiple columns based on value
I want to perform an operation where I spread values in a column to new columns, based on the same values in another column. See example below
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'B': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']})

   A   B
0  a  x1
1  a  x2
2  b  x3
3  b  x4

I want to transform this to
   A  B1  B2
0  a  x1  x2
1  b  x3  x4

for a larger dataframe with more rows and more columns. However the operation should be perfomed only on two columns.

You can achieve this this way:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'B': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']})

df['helper'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount() + 1
result = df.pivot(index='A', columns='helper', values='B')

result.columns = [f'B{i}' for i in result.columns]
result = result.reset_index()

print(result)


which gives
   A  B1  B2
0  a  x1  x2
1  b  x3  x4


Same answer as I got from my LLM haha :) I was wondering if pandas had a function to do this, but seems that is not the case. Thanks.

In a way, pivot is the function you are referring to.
